# I cannot use lua resty.http on Kong pre-function plugin

Tags: lua, gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I need to make a external security request before any request on my Kong Gateway.

To do that, I used the plugin Kong Functions (Pre-Plugins), which allows me to execute lua scripts before any request.

Script:

```
local http = require "resty.http"

-- Pega o valor do header 'token' da requisição
local token = kong.request.get_header("token")

-- Verifica se o header 'token' foi encontrado
if not token then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "token not found in request headers")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
end

-- Configuração da requisição HTTP
local httpc = http.new()
local res, err = httpc:request_uri("my_request_url", {
    method = "GET",
    headers = {
        ["token"] = token
    },
    ssl_verify = false
})

-- Verifica se houve algum erro na requisição
if not res then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to request token validation: ", err)
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
end

-- Verifica se a validação do token falhou
if res.status ~= 200 then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "token validation failed with status code: ", res.status)
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end
```

But I´m receiving this error:

```
init.lua:386 [pre-function] /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/kong-lua-sandbox.lua:171: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/tools/sandbox.lua:88: require 'resty.http' not allowed within sandbox,
```

I tried to add an env on my container:

```
  - name: KONG_LUA_SANDBOX_GLOBALS
    value: "package.loaded['resty.http'] = require 'resty.http'"
```

But I keep receiving the same error, even after restarting the container, I really don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm intrigued by this configuration:

> I tryed to add an env on my container:
>
> - name: KONG_LUA_SANDBOX_GLOBALS
>   value: "package.loaded['resty.http'] = require 'resty.http'"

I don't know any configuration named `lua_sandbox_globals`. Do you mean [`untrusted_lua_sandbox_requires`](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/3.2.x/reference/configuration/#untrusted_lua_sandbox_requires)?

By default Kong's serverless plugin [disallow](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/serverless-functions/#sandboxing) any `require` statement to be run, you can use the `untrusted_lua_sandbox_requires` to require the module without taking Kong out of sandbox mode.

If you want to add `resty.http` to the list of allowed package to be load. Set the module name as the value of the environment variable should be enough:

```
name: KONG_UNTRUSTED_LUA_SANDBOX_REQUIRES
value: resty.http
```